# Java not finding environment variables defined in Jenkins

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, centos, environment-variables

I have a snippet of code that is obtaining an environment variable as follows: `System.getenv("MY_VAL")`

locally on my windows machine this works fine.

However, on my Jenkins CI Server which is running CentOS I am encountering some issues

I have tried setting the value of MY_VAL through both the envinject plugin as well as the global jenkins settings

If i do a pre-build step to echo the value out, it works fine, however inside my java code this is not being resolved.

How do I get this to be resolved?

Comment: i think this may be because the java program is creating its own new terminal that obliterates all environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by installing [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=63144168) plugin.

1) After installing check the **Prepare an environment for the job** option in the job configuration screen. This option will display several field for you to fill.

**UPDATE**

2) Fill the **Script Content** area with a command `touch env.properties` to create the file.

3) Fill the **Properties Content**t field with the variables you want to inject inside your recently created **env.properties** file by doing so. Place one variable per line ex:

```
     VARIABLE1=value
     VARIABLE2=value
```

4) Reference **env.properties** file you've just created in the file path area.

5) At runtime Jenkins will inject those variables and they will be available to your program.

Comment: I tried placing MY_VAL=/my/path in the Properties Content field and ${WORKSPACE}/envInject.properties in Properties file path but it does not run as it says that the properties file does not exist. Does it not create one?

Comment: If it doesn't and just reads from the file, would the file just need to be empty?

Comment: @mangusbrother Not sure what the problem is but try $JENKINS_HOME instead of $WORKSPACE... if that doesn't work try filling the full path for your job's workspace... and if neither of those work uncheck *Prepare an envinronment job* option and add a new build step called inject variables or inject envinronment variables... can't remember the exact label... then do the same thing declaring those variables... you don't need to fill all fields... just the properties content and path... remember to place it before the Java program execution.

Comment: The plugin should create the properties file... it's just an auxiliary method that persists those parameters in a file to workround a Jenkins features that inject it's own env vars before each step... exemple of Jenkins vars? $WORKSPACE, $BUILD_NUMBER

Comment: If i set just a random name of a property file it stll says it does not exist @rogério-peixoto

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject this variable into property.file and then access this from property file. e.g. in execute shell you can define "echo MY_VAL=default > property.file" .. Later in subsequent jobs you can pass through using "Jenkins Parameterized Trigger plugin" where you have option to access parameters from property file.